# Как из карты гугла/яндекса по определённой ссылке сделать картинку средствами php?

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, php

Добрый день.

Можно ли из карты гугла/яндекса по определённой ссылке сделать картинку средствами php?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. static map называется.

Пример url:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<address>&zoom=14&size=<size>&key=<key>&sensor=false&markers=color:red|<imgName.png>
```

Вот мануал: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=ru

Comment: Спасибо огромное. А для яндекса такое-же есть? Просто я смотрел, там вроде надо координаты передавать. А можно ли улицу передать?

Comment: На счет яндекста не знаю. В гугл можно передавать именно адрес: Страна, город, улица, номер дома. И будет карта с маркером по адресу. Можно без маркера. Читайте мануал, там все есть